# Passar parâmetros para o método pela URL

Tags: c#, web-service, soap, querystring

Como eu faço para capturar os parâmetros solicitados pela URL em uma *webservice*?

Por exemplo: eu tenho a seguinte webservice: `http://localhost/teste/WebService1.asmx/Produto`

Como faço para passar os parâmetros do método `Produto`? Para que ficassem mais ou menos assim:

`http://localhost/teste/WebService1.asmx/Produto?a=sincroniza&dado=produto&id_vendedor=2666&id_grupo=1700&id_usuario=2925&id_empresa=2004`

E como eu faria pra ler isso?

Answer (score 2):

Antes de mais nada, esses parâmetros se chamam ***query string***.

Você pode declarar no seu método para que ele aceite requisições **HTTP GET**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)]
public string ConverterNumero(int param){ 
    ... 
}
```

E mudar no arquivo *web.config*

```xml
<system.web>
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
  </protocols>
...
</system.web>
```

Depois disso, poderá chamar seu *webservice* dessa forma

`http://site.com/Servico.asmx/ConverterNumero?param=1`

E o seu método `ConverterNumero` será chamado com o valor de `param` sendo **1**.

Comment: tá dando essa mensagem na hora de compilar. Seção de configuração não reconhecida webServices.

Comment: correção: não consigo publicar a webservice, "Seção de configuração não reconhecida webServices"

Comment: Eu removi [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet=true)], deixando somente no arquivo XML e funcionou

Comment: Eu estava mesmo vendo essa questão, vou editar a resposta logo que tiver algo mais concreto. Se alguma das respostas o ajudou a resolver o problema, você pode votar positivamente nela nas setinhas e escolhê-la como correta marcando o sinal abaixo das setas para votar.